# DefaultMultipartMessageReader vs SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader in webflux

Tags: multipartform-data, nio, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

In webflux, we have two different implementations for reading multipart request body

`DefaultMultipartMessageReader` & `SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader`

I see that both of them uses nio when writing. Since I am using netty (thru reactor netty), even reading from request body would be done using nio

If so, what is the purpose each of them serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Spring Framework 5.2, Spring WebFlux indeed ships with 2 multipart reader implementations.

In Spring Framework 5.0, the multipart reader implementation was relying on a 3rd party library (synchronoss) to read multipart requests in a non-blocking fashion. But this implemnetation is not fully reactive and can buffer data and write it to disk as a temporary file.

As of [spring-framework#21659](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21659), a new fully-reactive implementation has been introduced and is the new default. The first implementation remains as a possible choice for developers.

Comment: Does that mean, with new changes, If I use `Flux<Part> partFlux` as annotation endpoint method argument & read the Request body, the request body would be read lazily after I assembled my `Publisher` within the endpoint?

Comment: Yes, it would be read in a reactive fashion as soon as something subscribes. If the pipeline is returned by the controller handler, as soon as we can write to the response.

Comment: I just looked at the source & I see that the whole body is cached in memory using buffer. Wouldn't this be a huge problem as we are trying to load everything into memory before passing this data to the endpoint?

`DefaultMultipartMessageReader#read` -> `DataBufferUtils.split(body, boundaryNeedle)` -> `Flux.from(dataBuffers).flatMap(buffer -> endFrameOnDelimiter(buffer, matcher)).bufferUntil(buffer -> buffer == END_FRAME)`

Comment: I don’t think that’s the case. It’s hard to answer that in the comments section. Maybe create a new question to address that issue specifically? Feel free to ping me there.

Comment: I have added the questions in the issue itself. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21659

Comment: Can you please respond there. Thanks